# Make a tabcontrol with collapsed tabitem

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

How I can make a tabcontrol that contains tabitem parents of other tabitem and these are collapsed, similar to an accordion. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

Comment: could you show an image what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dpatra/accordion-in-wpf-toolkit/) for wpf and for winRT try [this](https://github.com/brendankowitz/ZeroProximity.Accordion). Have a look at expanderview.